# SQL obtaining the last two digits of integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to obtain the last two digits of an integer. Each element placed in the tables comes as a full year ie. `YYYY` and I only want the last two digits, so that all the fields show

```
YEAR
----
09
00
89
```

where the initialy field was

```
YEAR
----
2009
2000
1989
```

EDIT: I get a complaint saying,

`HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

when i try

`select right(cast(year as char),2) from subjects;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Postgres has borrowed (or inherited) the modulus operator from C:

```
SET search_path='tmp';

CREATE TABLE lutser ( year integer);

INSERT INTO lutser (year)
        SELECT generate_series(1991,2012)
    ;

SELECT year
    , year / 100 as c2
    , year % 100 AS y2
    FROM lutser
    ;
```

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 22
 year | c2 | y2 
------+----+----
 1991 | 19 | 91
 1992 | 19 | 92
 1993 | 19 | 93
 1994 | 19 | 94
 1995 | 19 | 95
 1996 | 19 | 96
 1997 | 19 | 97
 1998 | 19 | 98
 1999 | 19 | 99
 2000 | 20 |  0
 2001 | 20 |  1
 2002 | 20 |  2
 2003 | 20 |  3
 2004 | 20 |  4
 2005 | 20 |  5
 2006 | 20 |  6
 2007 | 20 |  7
 2008 | 20 |  8
 2009 | 20 |  9
 2010 | 20 | 10
 2011 | 20 | 11
 2012 | 20 | 12
(22 rows)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select substring(CAST(2012 as CHAR(4)), 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a LEN function on Postgres, but if it does, try this:

```
select SUBSTRING(year,len(year)-1,len(year))
```

Comment: when I tried using len() or length() function in postgresql it says that function doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below SQL query:

```
select to_char as year from to_char(current_timestamp, 'YY')
```

here we use last two digit of year from current_timestamp